# How to repair/mask/get rid of a sparkle on a floor tile

Tags: home, hardware

Recently a pile of plates fell on my kitchen floor. It chipped away a small piece of one of the kitchen floor tiles. That creates a small white sparkle while the tiles are gray. I would like to get rid of that chip, or repair it, but I don't know how.The tile is not broken though, only a small piece is missing and that small piece could not be found among the broken plates, unfortunately.

**Edit :**
Some pictures of the crack. Pen is for scale.
The floor tile is ceramic, I guess.
 [image: close up] [image: up view]

Comment: What kind of tile is it -- ceramic, stone, asphalt, something else?

Comment: I remember last week there was a usefull reply, is it gone now? Has it been deleted? I wanted to try it out this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you prefer to do it yourself, right? :)

I would do the following:

- use a small quantity of cement (any kind, preferably one that cures quickly);
- get some black/ dark-gray pigment for wall-paints;
- play with the proportions of cement and pigment - until you get the right shade; you should probably pre-dilute the pigment for easier results;
- the wet color may be quite different compared to end color, so create some small batches and let them dry (e.g. on a piece of paper);
- clean the white area in the tile. Any grease is a big enemy. Try to have a porous surface, for better adhesion of the cement;
- I would even try to make the hole bigger (mostly, deeper) - with the risk of breaking the tile, though; with good care, the tile should be fine though;

When everything is according to your preferences, apply the dyed cement to the white area, flatten it while not cured.

I noticed that there is a kind of a darker strip going through the chipped area. You may prepare 2 samples of cement, of different shades, to restore the stripe too.

Paint for cars may not work nice in your case because of the reflectiveness. Your tiles seems quite non-reflective.

---

**The quick and dumb solution**

Use a marker, or any other dirt to "paint" the white. Or do nothing, and dirt will take care of it anyway - but it will take a long time :(

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a grey crayon. For an exact colour match, you could melt both grey and black and use when solid.

Answer (score 0):

Match the color as best you can with an auto paint touch up selection system. You are essentially doing a touch up to repair a small ding, just like on a car. Also, just like paint touch up on your car, it won't be perfect but it will make it much less noticeable.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know exactly what to do, but you could maybe get another peice of that stone, cut it to the right shape, and put it back. if it isnt the right color, then do your best to find an exact match of the color on your stone and paint it that color. and if all else fails, you could always just replace the tile with a whole new one.